# Bootstrap "Panel-collapse" "collapse" do not work online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know why my classes *"panel-collapse" "collapse"* are not working.

I have just uploaded the files on my server and when I click the link area, they do not work (They do not drop the hidden content down). However,  they work perfectly on my Dreamweaver preview (In addition in the example code I have pasted below).

If you want to check the online version please check out to this link https://www.carloanfinder.co.uk/CLF30-WEB/CLF3_0_web-ONLY-FORM-v3.html and you can see as they do not work when you click the clickable area, for example the green area.

If someone want to check the code. Please find it below a small example what I am using. (It works here as well)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head>
<body>
  
  
   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#FAQ5">  <div class="col-md-12 form-clf-green-bar-bg">
     <!--F-2-header--> <p style="background-color: red"> CLICK ME </p> 
    </div> </a>
  
      <!--F-2-form--> 
       <div id="FAQ5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <!--contact us grey-->     <br class="cB" /><div  class="container-fluid"> 
         <div class="row form-bg-grey">
            <!--text--> <div class="col-md-12"> <h4>TEST HELLO!</h4>
          </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         </div>
 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS-CLF30.js"></script>

  
 </body>
</html>
```

Finally, please find blow an image what it should drop down (a form) when you click the green area (button)

[image]

If someone could tell me where is the error/bug, that would be amazing. Because I cannot understand where is the error. I have checked it on Chrome and Firefox.

Thank you very much

Comment: so we have to tell you the error and then we also have to solve your error ?

Comment: No, basically I would like to know where is the problem. Because it works offline (on my Dreamweaver) and in the code example I have pasted. However, I do not know why it does not work on my server.   

I do not if is something in my server or in the code. I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is right, but there is a problem loading http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

When using the inspector with the link you provided it says that file is not being loaded because of "mixed content": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Can you try to upload the bootstrap.min.js directly to your server and link the local version?

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. I am going to upload the boostrap.min.js  right now.  I will let you know if it works or not.

Comment: It works! 

https://www.carloanfinder.co.uk/CLF30-WEB/CLF3_0_web-ONLY-FORM-v4.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, the development console, either in Chrome or Firefox can help a lot to debug/edit websites: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Answer (score 1):

You are loading bootstrap.min from an http source on an https site and the browser is blocking the file due to [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).

[(See screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8FHj.png)

Switch to an https CDN link (or locally host the file) to solve your issue.